# Dynamically adding contents inside Jquery ui accordion doset work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

So I have this accordion code which has three input fields and two buttons

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>External Attendees</h3>
  <div>

    <div class="invitediv">
      <div class="form-row  invitepeople">

        <div class="col-3">

          <input type="text" class="form-control inmail" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">

          <input type="text" class="form-control inname" id="extname" placeholder="Name" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-3">

          <input type="text" class="form-control incnt" placeholder="Mobile No" />

        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
          <input type="button" id="reminvt" onclick="removeDiv(this);" class="btn btn-danger reminvt" value="-" />

        </div>

        <div class="col-1">
          <input type="button" id="addinvt" class="btn btn-success" value="+" />

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

on click this buttons calls this method

```
$("#addinvt").on("click", function (e) {
  debugger;

  e.preventDefault();
  var data =
    '</br> <div class="form-row  invitepeople" >' +
    '  <div class="col-3">' +
    ' <input type="text" class="form-control inmail" placeholder="Email" />' +
    " </div>" +
    '<div class="col-3">' +
    ' <input type="text" class="form-control inname" id="extname" placeholder="Name" />' +
    " </div>" +
    '<div class="col-3">' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control incnt" placeholder="Mobile No" />' +
    "</div>" +
    '<div class="col-1">' +
    ' <input type="button" id="reminvt" onclick="removeDiv(this);" class="btn btn-danger reminvt" value="-" />' +
    "</div>" +
    '<div class="col-1">' +
    '<input type="button" id="addinvt" class="btn btn-success" value="+" />' +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>";
  $(".invitediv").append(data);
});
```

and appends the HTML to the div inside the accordion, so my problem is the + button only works with the element that's already present inside the accordion, I'm able to add new inputs with it but the + button of the newly added elements doesn't work, what's happening here? can someone explain me?

Comment: When you are adding html(from data) then, you are getting duplicated rows, and that is in general bad. like addinvt

Comment: i know this is a bad practise but the app I works with needs this so the client can add as many names and mails as they want, and everything was working great before adding the inputs inside accordion, do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a unique id for each button, which I did here by doing this
`<input type="button" id="addinvt" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addDiv(this);" value="+" />`

Here, `var elemtnCount = document.querySelectorAll('.invitepeople').length;` first I checked how many elements you already have and then incremented it for generating a new key and then added it with the ID property for generating the unique ID.

and use a function for each add(+) button click. So your button will be unique as well as you will be adding buttons with every click.

Note: Here I only made changes for add button, do the same for the remove(-) button.

```js
function addDiv(e) {
            debugger;
var elemtnCount = document.querySelectorAll('.invitepeople').length;

var newElemCount = elemtnCount + 1;
           
            var data ='</br> <div class="form-row  invitepeople" >'+

              '  <div class="col-3">'+

                   ' <input type="text" class="form-control inmail" placeholder="Email" />'+
               ' </div>'+

                '<div class="col-3">'+

                   ' <input type="text" class="form-control inname" id="extname" placeholder="Name" />'+

               ' </div>'+
                '<div class="col-3">'+

                    '<input type="text" class="form-control incnt" placeholder="Mobile No" />'+

                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-1">'+
                   ' <input type="button" id="reminvt" onclick="removeDiv(this);" class="btn btn-danger reminvt" value="-" />'+

                '</div>'+

                '<div class="col-1">'+
                    '<input type="button" id="addinvt'+(newElemCount)+' " class="btn btn-success" onclick="addDiv(this);" value="+" />'+

                '</div>'+
            '</div>'
            $(".invitediv").append(data);

        };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
                <h3>External Attendees</h3>
                <div>

                    <div class="invitediv">
                        <div class="form-row  invitepeople">

                            <div class="col-3">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control inmail" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-3">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control inname" id="extname" placeholder="Name" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">

                                <input type="text" class="form-control incnt" placeholder="Mobile No" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1">
                                <input type="button" id="reminvt" onclick="removeDiv(this);" class="btn btn-danger reminvt" value="-" />

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-1">
                                <input type="button" id="addinvt" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addDiv(this);" value="+" />

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the remove button is working fine for some reason, leeme check add button with your code

Comment: no unfortunately your method dosent work either

Comment: may I know exactly where it's giving you an error?  is it working in the snippet that I provided here?